# RecurrenceTable does not work for sequence of function

Tags: functions, difference-equations

Consider the following code that repeatedly differentiates a function:

```
test = RecurrenceTable[ {g[n] == D[g[n - 1], x], g[0] == x^10}, 
  g, {n, 0, 5}]
```

This code repeatedly takes differentiation. However, the output is

```
RecurrenceTable[{g[n] == 0, g[0] == x^10}, g, {n, 0, 5}]
```

Why my code does not work? In particular, why my differentiation changed to 0? (For this simplified example, I can use `FoldList`, etc. However, what I want to do is quite complicated.)

Comment: I do not think R.T. works with derivatives, I think equations has to be algebraic. There was a similar question here   [recurrence-table-differentiation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127239/recurrence-table-differentiation)

Comment: "In particular, why my differentiation changed to 0?" --- Because `g[n - 1]` does not explicitly contain `x`.

Comment: Why not just `NestList[D[#, x] &, x^10, 5]`?

Comment: Since "However, what I want to do is quite complicated.", I strongly suggest not using `RecurrenceTable` because it has very limited capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

Given the recurrence

$$
g_n(t) = g'_{n-1}(t),\ \ \ g_0(t) = t^{10}
$$

After applying the Laplace transform we have the transformed sequence

$$
G_n(s) = s G_{n-1}(s),\ \ \ G_0(s) = \frac{10!}{s^{11}}
$$

so

```
solG = RSolve[{G[n]== s G[n-1], G[0] == 10!/s^11}, G, n][[1]];
Gs = G[n] /. solG;
gt = InverseLaplaceTransform[Gs, s, t]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rather general recipe that works for a surprisingly large class of problems.

First, define $g_n$ as a recursion (directly, without using [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)):

```
g[0] = x^10;
g[n_] := D[g[n - 1], x]
```

Compute a few terms:

```
terms = Table[{n, g[n]}, {n, 0, 10}]
(*    {{0, x^10}, {1, 10 x^9}, {2, 90 x^8}, {3, 720 x^7},
       {4, 5040 x^6}, {5, 30240 x^5}, {6, 151200 x^4},
       {7, 604800 x^3}, {8, 1814400 x^2}, {9, 3628800 x},
       {10, 3628800}}                                        *)
```

Try to find a general formula for these terms:

```
F = FindSequenceFunction[terms];
InputForm[F]
(*    DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {(n-11)*y[n] + x*y[n+1] == 0,
                                       y[1] == x^10}]][#1+1] &         *)
```

You can use the resulting [`DifferenceRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRoot.html) expression in further calculations (in a similar way as we can [work with `Root` objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13767/26598)), including for example the powerful [`DifferenceRootReduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DifferenceRootReduce.html) function that can simplify many expressions.